# Add github project as gradle dependency to extend its java class

Tags: maven, kotlin, gradle

I'm working on a rect-native project and I'm trying to add a custom component to an already existing library. I want to add my own component to [this library](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps). I don't want to fork on the original project and create it there because my component will have different libraries and I think it will be harder to maintain a fork.

So I'm trying to import the project as a gradle dependency on a project of my own to import the original class `AbstractMapFeature` and extend its features to create my own class. I'm new to gradle and I don't even know if this is possible.

But if so, how do I import the project?

I tried through jipack:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.rnmapbox:maps:+'
}
```

But got an error stating that it couldn't find the project. The project doesn't compile to jitpack as can be seen [here](https://jitpack.io/#rnmapbox/maps/).

I also tried to install it as a node dependency and import it local from there:

```
maven {
    url "$rootDir/node_modules/@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/android"
}
```

But I don't know how to import this into my code. Tried with:
`import com.mapbox.rctmgl.components.mapview.RCTMGLMapView`
Which is the same import statement they use, but got an error saying it couldn't find  `rctmgl`.

So I have two questions. Is it really possible to import the original project's code and use it on my own? And if yes, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Jitpack can't successfully work on any Github repo. If you look at the [instructions for that library](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/blob/main/android/install.md), there is a specific [open source fork  of the library called MapLibre](https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-native), which is what you'll need (assuming this is an Android project, since I otherwise don't see anything Java/Kotlin-specific). The library is published on `mavenCentral()` so you don't need Jitpack. You should specify the library as

```
implementation 'org.maplibre.gl:android-sdk:9.4.0'
```

If you're just creating a subclass of a class in the library, that's just normal usage of a library. If you need to actually swap out code that's in the library, you will have to fork it. If you're forking it, none of the above applies. You need to create a forked repo, make your changes, build it, and use the build from your fork as a dependency in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The open source fork is for the map implementation on android, this don't solve my issue because I need the code written for react native that is in the said project. In other words I need the classes avaliable [here](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/tree/main/android/rctmgl/src/main/java-v10/com/mapbox/rctmgl/components), to create my component and export to react native.

Comment: Looks like the instructions for using that version are here: https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/blob/main/android/install.md#mapbox-maps-sdk-v10 These instructions are terrible though. I honestly don't understand them. I don't see why creating a couple of variables in `ext` would be enough to make it a project dependency.